# Angular 2 - how do TypeScript declaration files get loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm exploring Angular 2 (Typescript) by reading through the tutorial and the [quick start] (https://github.com/angular/quickstart).

I'm curious how a declaration file `.d.ts` is loaded by the TypeScript compiler.

If I put a `.d.ts` file in the `root` folder or the `/app` folder, it seems the TypeScript compiler just picks it up itself. There is no other reference to this file, and yet I can use the variable declared in this file anywhere in the project without a compiler error.

If I put a `.d.ts` file inside a sub folder under `node_modules`, the compiler doesn't pick it up itself like the previous example.

So, how does the compiler know what `.d.ts` files to load? It just load all `.d.ts` files under the `root` and its sub folders except under `node_modules`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). The most relevant excerpts being:

> The presence of a tsconfig.json file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a TypeScript project.
>
> [...]
>
> If the "files" and "include" are both left unspecified, the compiler defaults to including all TypeScript (.ts, .d.ts and .tsx) files in the containing directory and subdirectories except those excluded using the "exclude" property
>
> [...]
>
> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.

Comment: My `tsconfig.json` doesn't have `exclude`. Why doesn't the compiler include files under `node_modules`?

Comment: Because, as the documentation says: *The "exclude" property defaults to excluding the node_modules, bower_components, jspm_packages and <outDir> directories when not specified.*